# re-ordering rows of a table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a sql table,it will give output when `select * from table` is given

```
o/p: change
     profile
     new
```

how can i get output as follows

```
o/p: new
     change
     profile
```

Comment: Table definition please. Will the table always have exactly 3 rows, with the same data? (Odd way to use a dbms...)

Comment: table contains two columns 1)name 2)url

Comment: On what basis you want them to be sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an expression in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from the_table
order by case 
            when the_column = 'new' then 1
            when the_column = 'change' then 2
            when the_column = 'profile' then 3
            else 4
         end;
```

Comment: I thought about it this way, but im not sure if they are the only 3 names used, we have only just established its mysql not sql so god knows! If it is only 3 this is the best method

Comment: @matt "*it's mysql not sql*" does not make sense. MySQL uses SQL as a query language (my answer is standard SQL and should work in MySQL as well). If you have a dynamic number of values, you should put them into a separate table with a `sort_order` column and then join those table.

Comment: if i inserted another row again i have to change the code?

Comment: @sada: yes, if you need this dynamically, create a lookup table with a `sort_order` column and join against it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp server then it is very easy change. Go to phpMyadmin page in that you can reorder the rows as you wish.